# Show .MSG file with Outlook in C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, com, outlook, msg

Is there a way (some specific COM object) which can be integrated into your app window and **render** the content of .MSG file? There are solutions for parsing .MSG files but I'd like to easily display it. Emails with tables, links and especially images are very tricky to render correctly - as I understand, only Outlook is able to render is accurately in a shape user is accustomed to.

Even Preview Handler cripples email formatting - you can notice it in Windows Explorer's Preview Pane. I guess the only reliable solution is to ask Outlook to render it for you...

Comment: You² might want to have a look at https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader, some foreign encodings might need a bit more work but in general it's a good starting point. (²If you'd still have that problem that  is, which is rather unlikely - but other users coming from google here might wanna know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider automating Outlook to display the .msg files. See [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819398) for more information.

Also you may consider using third-party components for getting the job done.

Comment: Thanks, opening it in new window with `_MailItem.Display()` is suitable for the time being.